# Regular expression find matching string then delete everything between spaces

Tags: python, regex

Pretty new to regex here so I'm not sure how to do this. FYI I'm using Python but I'm not sure how much that matters.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
string1 = 'Metro boomin on production wow'
string2 = 'A loud boom idk why I chose this as an example'
pattern = 'boom'
result = re.sub(pattern, ' ____ ', string1)
result2 = re.sub(pattern, ' ____ ', string2)
```

right now that would give me `"Metro ____in on production wow"` and `"a loud ____ idk why I chose this as an example`

What I want is both `"Metro ______ on production wow"` and `"a loud ____ idk why I chose this as an example"`

Basically I want to find a target string in another string, then replace that matching string and everything between 2 spaces into a new string

Is there a way I can do this? Also if possible, preferably with variable length in my replacement string based on the length of the original string

Comment: Use a regexp that matches a word containing `boom`.

Comment: Using @coldspeed answer, you should then be able to adapt the length of the replacement by leveraging the ability to specify functions as replacements in `re.sub`. Have a look at `re.sub` documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Just extend your regex a bit.

```
In [105]: string = 'Metro boomin on production wow'

In [106]: re.sub('boom[\S]*', ' ____ ', string)
Out[106]: 'Metro  ____  on production wow'
```

And,

```
In [137]: string2 = 'A loud boom'

In [140]: re.sub('boom[\S]*', ' ____', string2)
Out[140]: 'A loud  ____'
```

The `\S*` symbol matches zero or more of everything that is not a space.

To replace text with the same number of underscores, specify a lambda callback instead of a replacement string:

```
re.sub('boom[\S]*', lambda m: '_' * len(m.group(0)), string2)
```

Comment: this wouldn't work for me because there are also situations where there is nothing after my target string

Comment: @EdwardFu Have you tried it? It does work. If there is nothing after the target string, it'll match till the end, which is what you want, right?

Comment: @EdwardFu `\S` is just a short form for `[a-zA-Z_]` and a bunch of other characters you might find in a word (anything that is not a space). It doesn't mean "match till the next space", no.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I added another example to my question, but in the case that there is nothing after the pattern, it doesn't seem like it is replacing the string

Comment: @EdwardFu Ah, you didn't mention the `in` part was optional. Edited. It WILL work now.

Comment: @COLDSPEED yup my bad, it works now! thanks for the help :)